# USB/HDD not detected

Tags: usb, hard-drive, 20.04, laptop

My system after a fresh install does not detect any external USB devices which were previously detected. I tried various USB devices but not detected. They worked fine on the same laptop until the fresh install.

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:5776 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. HP Truevision HD
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:b001 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1d57:fa60 Xenta 2.4G Receiver
**Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0781:5567 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Blade**
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

but lsblk or disks doesnt show any external devices - just the OS installed HDD
And all my bluetooth devices seem to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue with Nvidia graphics driver. Solved it by downgrading the driver.